# Arranging 3 cards inside 8 columns with a right margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three cards that i want to fix inside 8 columns and leave a 10px margin to the right.

This is the code

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-8">

      <div class="top_stories row">
      <div class="card col-md-4 " >
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="card col-md-4 " >
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="card col-md-4 cw" >
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>hello world</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

I have 10px margin using this code

```
.card{
    margin-right: 10px !important;
}
```

This is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s017mn4d/

Is there a method i can use to fit 3 equal card widths inside 8 columns?.

Comment: It's not clear to me what result you want. Which three of the columns should have the card? Should the other, empty, columns be equally wide?

Comment: Have you checked the code? I have 3 md-4 columns. Currently they cant fit well and have a margin separating them. If you see the code its clear to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `.card` in `.col-md-4` divs. I also added `padding-right: 0` and `padding-left: 0` for col-md-4. Because it has 15px right and left padding as default.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.card {
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

/* added */
.col-md-4 {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="top_stories row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card ">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card cw">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```